# Stripe Credit card Payment

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I was wondering if anyone can suggest a good step by step tutorial for implementing a purchase/check out system in my code using one these third parties like stripe and connecting it to a backend server. I could not find anything helpful for a beginner on the net so far.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no absolute solution to your question. Especially when talking about processing user payments. You should always refer to documentation of a provider you're going to use and their best practices. This process is also strongly depends on your backend implementation. It could be achieved via API on backend side, or it could solely depend on client implementation. This question is really too broad.

Comment: since I am a beginner I decided to follow Stripe tutorial which is using this GitHub for reference: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example/Standard%20Integration%20(Swift)

if you go to the readme file in step 3 it says:Open ./Stripe.xcworkspace (not ./Stripe.xcodeproj) with Xcode

I am not sure how to do this step. Can you help me?

Comment: @Sara you need to download the example project and open it